# EF 4 – MVC3: Saving complex object graph (nested one-to-many relationship)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a Code First EF 4.1 model that looks like this:

http://pct.staging.xeed.nl/images/model.png

Objects of this model are serialized to JSON to be processed in the browser using jQuery. In jQuery this object graph is instantiated as a Javascript object. User interactions ( add/delete actions, and add/delete tasks) result in a modification of the Javascript object. When a new task or action object is added to the graph, it will get ID = 0. When a task or action object is deleted, it will get ui_status=”deleted”. Upon a save event in the user interface, the modified Javascript object is serialized to JSON and sent to the ‘AssignmentController’.

My problem is that I cannot figure out what is the best way to deal with saving this object graph. I keep on running into problems getting errors like (1) ‘Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed’ or (2) ‘An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager’.

(ad 1)  – I get this error when trying to delete an action from a task.

(ad 2)  – I get this error when trying to save 2 or more new objects at once. New objects all have ID=0, which is probably what causes this error.

Here is my code:

```
        // POST: /Assignment/Save/assignment
    [HttpPost]
    public string Save([Bind(Exclude="date")] Assignment assignment )
    {
        string message;

        assignment.date = DateTime.Now;
        Session["currentAssignment"] = assignment;

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return "Please Log in first.";
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            assignment.username = User.Identity.Name;

            if (assignment.tasks != null)
            {
                foreach (var task in assignment.tasks.ToList())
                {
                    db.Tasks.Attach(task);

                    if (task.actions != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var action in task.actions.ToList())
                        {
                            db.Actions.Attach(action);

                            if ((task.ui_status == "deleted" || action.ui_status == "deleted"))
                            {
                                if (action.actionID > 0)
                                {
                                    db.Entry(action).State = EntityState.Deleted;

                                }
                                else
                                {   //object was deleted from a new object graph
                                    //just save it with ui_status="deleted", it will be deleted from the db next time around
                                }
                            }
                            else if (action.actionID == 0)
                            {
                                db.Entry(action).State = EntityState.Added;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                db.Entry(action).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if (task.ui_status == "deleted")
                    {
                        if (task.taskID > 0)
                        {
                            db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                        }
                        else
                        {   //object was deleted from a new object graph
                            //just save it with ui_status="deleted", it will be deleted from the db next time around
                        }
                    }
                    else if (task.taskID== 0)
                    {
                        db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Added;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }

                }
            }

            db.Assignments.Attach(assignment);
            db.Entry(assignment).State = assignment.assignmentID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return js.Serialize(assignment);
        }
    }
```

I have been struggling with this for a while now, read all the posts. I would think that EF would take care of something like this, as most nontrivial applications will run into this.

Any thoughts on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you solved it you should have posted it as an answer to your own question and accept it instead, that way people won't try to answer this question in vain and also make it more clear for everyone what the solution was.

Comment: quite right, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the problem myself. I first updated the object graph by first setting EntityState.Added /EntityState.Modified to each object. Then I call db.SaveChanges() and run through all the objects again to set EntityState.Deleted when required. Then I call db.SaveChanges() once more.

here is the code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public string Save([Bind(Exclude="date")] Assignment assignment )
    {
        string message;

        assignment.date = DateTime.Now;
        Session["currentAssignment"] = assignment;

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return "Please Log in first.";
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            assignment.username = User.Identity.Name;

            if (assignment.tasks != null)
            {
                foreach (var task in assignment.tasks.ToList())
                {
                    if (task.actions != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var action in task.actions.ToList())
                        {
                            db.Entry(action).State = action.actionID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                    }
                    db.Entry(task).State = task.taskID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            db.Entry(assignment).State = assignment.assignmentID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (assignment.tasks != null)
            {
                foreach (var task in assignment.tasks.ToList())
                {
                    if (task.actions != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var action in task.actions.ToList())
                        {
                            if ((task.ui_status == "deleted" || action.ui_status == "deleted"))
                            {
                                db.Entry(action).State = EntityState.Deleted; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (task.ui_status == "deleted")
                    {
                        db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    }
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            return js.Serialize(assignment);
        }
```

Hope this helps anyone running into similar problems in the future.